# Making a list of lists with Python

Tags: python, list

I have run into something that is odd to me and having looked at some of the posts here I can't seem to find anyone trying to do something similar. So I am trying to create a list of lists something like this:

```
group1 = range(1-10)
group2 = range(10-20)
group3 = range(20-30)
group4 = range(30-40)
group5 = range(40-49)

groups = [group1, group2,group3,group4,group5]
```

This seems to result in a list of 5 empty lists. What gives? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `-` is subtraction. `range(x-y)` should be `range(x,y)`

Comment: Range uses , instead of - so it's more like range(1,10)

Comment: `range(1-10) == range(-9)`

Comment: range(1-10) == range(0, -9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `range(1-10)` you are really substracting 10 from 1, i.e. `range(1-10)` evaluates to `range(-9)`. The correct syntax is `range(1,10)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use `range(1,10)`.

Second, you won't get a list, you'll get a `range` object which is a generator. If you want an actual list, then you'll have to do `list(range(1,10))`

Comment: This applies only to Python 3.

Comment: Yes, 3.x returns range. 2.x returns a list. But, you can still run the above code. It won't throw an error. Though it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to have a list of lists of ranges between `1..10` then `10..20` and so on.

So, you can do something like that using `list comprehension` like this example:

```
a = ((1, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 49))
final = [list(range(*val)) for val in a]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]]
```

Comment: `[range(start, end) for start, end in a]` is sufficient, or even `[range(*values) for values in a]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But can you explain how to expose the ranges explicitly without having [range(1,10), range(10,20),...]

Comment: For Python 3 you need to wrap it with `list` = `[list(range(*values)) for values in a]`. In Python 2, it works as is.

Comment: Wel this is why i used list comprehension within python3. I don't use python2. Thanks for your comment i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this was the result of a brain cramp! I am using Python 2, and had I specified the range correctly it would have worked as expected.